# Can't get the spring-ws apache camel example to work

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, spring-ws

I've downloaded the latest binary distribution of Apache Camel for Windows(2.16.x) from the Apache Camel website but now I can't get the given Spring-ws example to work (see: http://camel.apache.org/spring-ws-example.html). When I try to run the service with the command "mvn clean install jetty:run" I get the following error:

> Line 36 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 36; columnNumber: 45;
>   cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'local' is not allowed to appear in
>   element 'ref'.

The spring-ws-servlet.xml looks exactly like the one in the downloaded example:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-spring-ws/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ws-servlet.xml

What's the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is exactly what you describe in your post. Can you show your   `spring-ws-servlet.xml`

Comment: I could reproduce this, the example from the official repo is indeed breaking

Comment: Thanks I logged a ticket about this bug in the example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9231